# Java - How to store values of a text file into an array using Scanner?

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;

public class textFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\DataGym.in.txt"));
        int maxIndx = -1;
        String text[] = new String[1000];
        while (sf.hasNext()) {
            maxIndx++;
            text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
        }

        sf.close();

        double average[] = new double[100];

        for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(text[j]);
            int k = 0;
            while (k <= 10) { //attempt to store all the values of text file (DataGym.in.txt) into the array average[] using Scanner
                average[k] = sc.nextDouble();
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code doesn't work and keeps giving me this error at the place where I store sc.nextDouble() into the k element of the array:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException:
>
> null (in java.util.Scanner)

Comment: Have you tried using `System.out.println` statements to check that `text[j]` actually contains what you think it does? Also, maybe you want `k < 10` instead of `k <= 10`.

Comment: Better yet, step through your code one line at a time in your IDE debugger to see what's actually happening.  In this case the exception means the input didn't contain what you were expecting.

Comment: You're only putting data into the first 10 elements of the `average` array, because you reset the index to 0 for every line

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It is suspicious that you have a call to `Scanner.hasNext()` with a following call to `Scanner.nextLine()`. There are complimentary calls to check and then get from a `Scanner`. For instance if you really want the next line then you should check if `Scanner.hasNextLine()` before calling `Scanner.nextLine()`. Similarly you call `Scanner.nextDouble()` without preceding it with a call to `Scanner.hasNextDouble()`.

Also like some of the comments mention you should use a debugger or print statements to see if you are getting what you expect you should be getting. Steps like this are necessary to debugging.

For instance after `sf.close` you could use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text))` and judge if the array contains what you expect.

Hope this helps your debugging.